# Keep the screen from activating when the phone is in my pocket

Tags: 2.1-eclair, motorola-milestone, lock-screens, proximity-sensor

I usually use my phone without a lock screen, so I can start using it by just pressing a button. Problem is, the camera and volume buttons on my Motorola Milestone are really light, and are easy to press accidentally in my pocket.

Since it already has a proximity sensor, is there a way I can tell it to completely ignore key presses when the proximity sensor detects something? My intention is to keep it from activating the touch screen if I accidentally press one of the physical buttons while it's in my pocket.

**EDIT** To be clear:
I want the safety of not activating my phone when it's in my pocket, and I want the convenience of not having to go through an unlock-the-screen step when it's not in my pocket.

It might be asking too much, but I thought I'd give it a try. I've read that *Tasker* might be able to achieve that, but I don't really know how it works and have no idea if it supports that functionality.

Comment: Well, that is the purpose of a lock-screen, isn't it? You don't want to use the lock-screen, but you want some functionality that mimics a lock-screen?

Comment: I want the best of both. :-) I want the safety of not activating my phone when it's in my pocket, and I want the convenience of not having to go through an unlock-the-screen step when it's not in my pocket.

Comment: I'd say use a really simple lock screen, like the "Puzzle" one ... 0.1 seconds and you're in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tasker can switch on/off the lock screen and can trigger events based on the orientation of your phone.

So you could set up an event in Tasker that enabled the lock screen when your phone is oriented vertically but upside down, then always place your phone in your pocket that way up.

Comment: Ok that's helpful. So tasker really can't check for the proximity sensor? =/

Comment: I tested it out and it can use the proximity sensor, but it's very shaky, so I decided to go with your idea.

Comment: Cool, hope it worked out OK! :)

Answer (score 2):

[Proximity Autolock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuts.autolock&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5udXRzLmF1dG9sb2NrIl0.) is an app that uses the proximity sensor to lock the phone when it is in your pocket, and you can disable the lock screen via the settings.